# Check the details of columns which have attributes applied to them

Tags: kdb

In the splayed tables we can find the details/order of columns in the .d file.
I was searching if there is any file which maintains the attributes information of the columns in a table.
How can we find the details of the attributes in the file system?

```
t:([] a:1 2 3; b:4 5 6; c:`a`b`c)
`:/home/st set .Q.en[`:/home/st;t]
get `:/home/st/.d / Output - `a`b`c
@[`:/home/st/;`a;`s#] / Is there any place in file system where we can find the attribute applied to a column
meta get `:/home/st/ / Show that attribute s is applied on column a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes details are stored in the column file itself. For example, in your case file `/home/st/a` will contain sorted attribute information.

But since these files are serialized data (binary format), and structure of splayed binary data is not open, we can not get the attribute information directly from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually read the attributes from columns on disk, it's just not recommended (and potentially subject to change):

```
q){(0x0001020304!``s`u`p`g)first read1(x;3;1)}`:st/a
`s
q){(0x0001020304!``s`u`p`g)first read1(x;3;1)}`:st/b
`
```